# Html and css to email php laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, api

```
public function send_email_to_students(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'class_name' =>'required',
            'converted_text'=>'required',
        ]);
        
        $class_id=class_room::where("class_name",request('class_name'))->get();
        $teacher= Teacher::where("teacher_id",$class_id[0]->teacher_id)->get();
        
        $converted_text =request("converted_text");
        // $html2TextConverter = new \Html2Text\Html2Text($converted_text);
        // $text = Html2Text::convert($converted_text);
        // $text = (new Parser())->parseString($converted_text);

        $converter = new \Markdownify\ConverterExtra;
        
        $text = html_entity_decode($converted_text, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');

        $data = array('teacher'=>$teacher[0]->first_name,'body' => $text);

        $sendmail=  Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) {
            $class_name= request("class_name");
        $class_id=class_room::where("class_name",$class_name)->get();

        $students=Student::where("class_id",$class_id[0]->class_id)->get();
        $emails=array();
        $names =array();
        foreach ($students as $value)
        {
            array_push($emails,$value->email);
            array_push($names,$value->first_name);
        }
            $message->setContentType('text/html');
            $message->to($emails , $names)->subject
               ('This is your converted text');
            $message->from('hello@dyslexia.test','Piece Of Words');
            // $message->html('<html>HTML version of the body</html>');
         });
        //  Mail::set("Content-Type","text/html");
      
        if (empty($sendmail)) { 
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Mail Sent Sucssfully'], 200); 
        }else{
             return response()->json(['message' => 'Mail Sent fail'], 400); 
            }

    }
```

This my api call I am sending an email using api and mailgun in laravel everything is working fine and the email is being sent but I change the content to be for exemple:
`<h1 style="color:blue">This is the content <h1>`

I tried using some html2text converter but its not converting css is there a way to do that?

Thank you for your help!!

SOLUTION:
I had put {{$body}} in the emails.welcome when I changed it to {!!$body!!} it worked fine it was sending it with special characters and it changed to html

Comment: Why not use the `emails.welcome` blade as it's meant to be used instead of attempting to pass HTML in?

Comment: because I have to pass html from the frontend as I am changing the text color using javascript

Comment: Everything is working thank you for your help!  @aynber